# non zero solution of $y'(t)=f(x,t)y(t)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

One of the examples in my textbook mentions that $y'(t)=f(x,t)y(t)$ has nonzero solution if and only if $f(x,t)$ does not depend on $x$. Why is this?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is $x$? Any relation between $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0):

From your equation it follows that $$f(x,t) = \frac{y'(t)}{y(t)}, (\forall t \text{, s.t. } y(t)\ne 0)$$ Where the r.h.s only depends on $t$, so naturally the l.h.s. must also be constant in $x$.